# Rails associations for mailing list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, mailing

I want to create something like mailings with mailing lists.

Users belong to mailing lists and mailing lists have many users.

I'm having trouble creating multiple inputs for users which to display list_names and save list_ids.

I have this code:

```
  .form-group
    =u.label :mailing_list_id, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label"
    .col-sm-10
      = u.association :mailing_list, :label => false , :input_html => { :class => 'form-control' }
```

It doesn't save changes.

I changed this code to:

```
  .form-group
    =u.label :mailing_list_id, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label"
    .col-sm-10
      = u.collection_select :mailing_list_id, MailingList.all, :id, :name, :multiple => true, :label => false , :input_html => { :class => 'form-control' }
```

Now the changes are saving. But it's displaying list_ids not list_names and I can't set multiselect options for this input.

Schema db:

```
create_table "mailing_lists", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
```

end

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.string   "address"
t.float    "latitude"
t.float    "longitude"
t.integer  "mailing_list_id"
```

end

```
Class MailingList has_many : users
Class User belongs_to :mailing_list
```

Do I need to create a join table?

I'm learning ruby and ruby on rails from zero, so I accept every criticism :)

Thanks

Comment: why not just use Rails mailers? They're pretty easy to trigger through models/controller actions.

Comment: I want to learn ruby and ruby on rails so i want to write something like this from zero

Comment: There's no need to reinvent the wheel (and I think that's a big part of learning Rails).

Comment: Yes, i know DRY etc. But if i have problem with this why don't resolve. It's just for me so it will be my reinvented the door :)